# How can I dismiss a nspopover from within a view?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, nspopover

I am writing a MacOS using Swift & SwiftUI. I am really very new to this, but I am a seasoned programmer.

The app is a menu bar app with one NSPopover. In the AppDelegate I include:

```swift
self.popover = NSPopover()
self.popover.contentViewController = NSHostingController(rootView: contentView)
```

Within the `contentView`, is it possible to include a button which closes the popover?

Answer (score 0):

You can find your NSPopover in a responder chain and then close it. To implement this you should make a coordinator for your close button:

```swift
struct CloseButton: NSViewRepresentable {

    class Coordinator: NSObject {
        @objc func click(_ button: NSButton) {
            var responder: NSResponder? = button
            while responder != nil {
                responder = responder?.nextResponder
                if let popover = responder as? NSPopover {
                    popover.close()
                    break
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func makeNSView(context: NSViewRepresentableContext<Self>) -> NSButton {
        NSButton(title: "Close", target: context.coordinator, action: #selector(Coordinator.click(_:)))
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> CloseButton.Coordinator {
        return Coordinator()
    }
    
    func updateNSView(_ nsView: NSButton, context: NSViewRepresentableContext<Self>) {
    }
}
```